# Get value from hash with two keys

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a `hash` whose keys are an array of two elements like this:

```
logs_data = 
{
    [ 143184, 11467 ] => {
          :finished => true,
        :created_at => 2017-11-09 09:38:11 UTC
    },
    [ 143184, 11471 ] => {
          :finished => true,
        :created_at => 2017-12-20 07:21:02 UTC
    }
}
```

I don't know how to get the value from a key. I tried this way:

```
logs_data[143184, 11467]
#=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

but it failed.

Comment: logs_data[[143184, 11467]]

Comment: variable name is 'logs_data' not 'logs' so use 'logs_data[[143184, 11467]]'

Comment: @lg86 Edit, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2.4.2 :027 > logs_data.keys
 => [[143184, 11467], [143184, 11471]]
```

your key is `[143184, 11467]` so you have to do `hash[key]` like following

```
2.4.2 :028 > logs_data[[143184, 11467]]
 => {:finished=>true, :created_at=> 2017-11-09 09:38:11 UTC}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works

Answer (score 0):

You need two sets of brackets logs_data[[ key ]]

In ruby you can also do logs_data.keys or logs_data.values